# Monaoc Editor (ngx-monaco-editor) in Angular is not reponding to newly added action (Ctrl + L) for clearing editor, for the first try

Tags: angular, hotkeys, monaco-editor, registerhotkey, ngx-monaco-editor

I have added a new action (Hot key - Ctrl + L) to clear editor window using the code below. It does call the defined clearEditor() function but editor is not refreshing/clearing out. I manually have to change tab and come back to monaco editor tab to see the results.

HTML

```
  <ngx-monaco-editor
       style="height: 100%"
       (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
        #monaco
        [options]="codeEditorOptions"
        [(ngModel)]="cipherCode"
        (onInit)="onInit($event)">
 </ngx-monaco-editor>
```

TS

```
onInit(editor: any) {
    this._editor = editor;
    this.enableShortcuts();
  }

  enableShortcuts() {
    this._editor.addAction({
      id: "clearQuery",
      label: "Clear Current Query",
      keybindings: [(window as any).monaco.KeyMod.CtrlCmd | (window as any).monaco.KeyCode.KeyL],
      contextMenuGroupId: "3_execution",
      run: () => {
        this.clearEditor();
      },
    });
  }

  clearEditor() {
    console.log("clear Called");
    this.cipherCode = '';
  }
```

Comment: please share stackblitz